# SQL Server Libraries for Java

Tags: java, sql-server

I'm curious to find what SQL Server libraries are available for Java.

At present we are using the com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver driver.  I think this was downloaded from the Microsoft site a while ago.

What alternative libraries are available?

Many thanks,

Andez

Answer (score 2):

[DataDirect](https://www.progress.com/data-sources/sql-server) is a well known alternative (used by many vendors) but also others such as

- [connx](http://www.connx.com/products/jdbc.html)
- [attunity](http://www.attunity.com/attunity_connect_jdbc_drivers)
- [i-net](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/jdbc-driver/ms-sql)
- [Easysoft](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/index.html)

[JTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) is an open source alternative

NB: I have only used the MS driver, DataDirect and the i-net drivers suceccfully in production, mostly prior to the MS JDBC driver release.

Comment: I can't recommend jTDS highly enough. It is so much better than the Microsoft driver it's not even funny.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of all of these and have been looking for alternatives to JDBC recently.

Comment: jTDS is good tho it is out of date now and doesn't fully support some of the newer datatypes like date and datetime2.  It almost supports them fully just it can't interpret column types probably when using the JDBC metadata classes.

Comment: @All - thanks for that.  Gonna check them out to see whats what.  Will checkout DataDirect and jTDS first me thinks.

Comment: @oluies - DataDirect is a fully paid component whose licence agreement looks quite scary.  Do you know roughly how much it costs?  I am always a little wary of vendors who don't put pricing information on their website.

Comment: @andez they are pretty expensive I think, they have OEM and regular licences what are you looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Seconding the [open source jTDS Driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net).  It also works perfectly with Hibernate.